# How do I attach multiple images to an email on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

In my application I want to attach multiple photos to an email in code, and also to post multiple photos to a web component.  I had done this in Android by zipping them and posted them by adding the boundary in between.

On the iPhone, is there a direct way to attach multiple images to an email, or do I have to zip them all?

Comment: if you use MFMailComposeViewController you can add attachments with -addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are thinking is very correct. you must do that to upload multiple files.

check 
http://code.developwithus.com/iphone/upload-image-and-data-with-iphone-sdk/
for single upload
and use your idea for multiple upload.

you may doubt in line
NSString *postData = [Utility getHTTPBodyParamsFromDictionary:record];
but that is not more than,
param1=one&param2=two, like that, which is insert in different file

let me know if you found any trouble

Answer (score 13):

To provide attachments to an email message, you'll want to use an MFMailComposeViewController, and set it up with code like the following:

```
mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailViewController setSubject:emailSubject];
[mailViewController setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
[mailViewController addAttachmentData:emailAttachment1 mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"Image1.jpg"];
[mailViewController addAttachmentData:emailAttachment2 mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"Image2.jpg"];
```

You can then present this view controller to the user, where they can fill in the rest of the message and send it.  In the example above, `emailSubject` and `emailBody` are NSString instances, and `emailAttachment1` and `emailAttachment2` are NSData instances that contain the raw data for the images to be attached.

You can add as many attachments as you need to the message this way.

Comment: Thanks men thanks a lot for your help this really help me in my app.