# Implementing email with attachments

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, email, attachment

In my iPhone app, I have a view where I am showing the names of files stored in the Documents directory.

These files are downloaded from a server, and now I want to implement an email function into my application.

My questions are:

1. Can I attach more than one file, and if so, what is yhe maximum number of files that can be attached?
2. When I attach a file, do I have to give the location where it is stored?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I attach multiple images to an email on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107926/how-do-i-attach-multiple-images-to-an-email-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using the stock [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html), you can add more than one attachment using `addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:`. You have to attach the raw data, so you'll need to fetch the file from disk and get an `NSData` representation. Here's an example of how to add to add a `UIImage` as an attachment:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mvc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mvc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mvc setSubject:@"My Subject"];
[mvc setMessageBody:@"My Message Body" isHTML:NO];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 1);
[mvc addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"image.jpg"];

[self presentModalViewController:mvc animated:YES];
[mvc release];
```