# Attach multiple image in mail in iPhone

Tags: iphone, image, excel, email

I want attach multiple images in mail programmatically. Is there any way possible to attach the photos as zip and attach it to mail.

Is there another way to send text and images as Excel supported file in iPhone?

Comment: Already answered at this link:-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107926/how-do-i-attach-multiple-images-to-an-email-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `-addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:` multiple times.

I've used below code to attach multiple images :-

```
mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailViewController setSubject:yourSubject];
[mailViewController setMessageBody:yourBodyMsg isHTML:NO];
[mailViewController addAttachmentData:emailAttachment1 mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"abc.jpg"];
[mailViewController addAttachmentData:emailAttachment2 mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"xyz.jpg"];
```

Comment: I want to zip the photos and attach the folder in mail