# How to attach multiple files in single mail in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to send multiple attachment files in single mail in iOS programatically. I have tried the following so far:

```
 // I give the file from array 
NSString *str_mail = [readingEmfReading objectAtIndex:0];
//  here I can encode the file
NSData *myData = [str_mail dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
//here I can attach the file with extance of .csv
[controller addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@".cvs" fileName:retriveEmail]  
//here I can set the body for mail 
[controller setMessageBody:@"file" isHTML:NO];
//here code for sent mail
if (controller) [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

By using this code, I can only send one attachment. I want to send multiple files however. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Below is another stack over flow link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107926/how-do-i-attach-multiple-images-to-an-email-on-the-iphone This might help you

Comment: call the method `–addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:` any times you'd like to add an attachment, it is an kind of _add_ not a kind of _set_ method (see the prefix)... the difference is obvious, but the documentation could also help, if you are unsure.

Answer (score 1):

you add many time addAttachmentData and add muliple file

try this code :- 
    add the this line

```
NSString *str_mail = [readingEmfReading objectAtIndex:0];
//  here i can encoded the file
NSData *myData = [str_mail dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

NSData *myData1 = [str_mail dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
//here i can attach the file with extance of .csv
[controller addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@".cvs" fileName:retriveEmail]  
//here i can set the body for mail 


// For second file 

NSData *myData1 = [str_mail dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

[controller addAttachmentData:myData1 mimeType:@".cvs" fileName:retriveEmail] 

[controller setMessageBody:@"file" isHTML:NO];
//here code for sent mail
if (controller) [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
        {
            [mailController setMailComposeDelegate:self];
            NSString* message=@"";
            NSString *filePath;
            for (int i=0; i<filesarray.count; i++)
            {
                if (i==filesarray.count-1)
                {
                    message=[message stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ ",[filesarray objectAtIndex:i]];
                }
                else if (i==filesarray.count-2)
                {
                    message=[message stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ and ",[filesarray objectAtIndex:i]];
                }
                else
                    message=[message stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@, ",[filesarray objectAtIndex:i]];
                NSString *datPath =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
                datPath = [datPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@.csv",[filesarray objectAtIndex:i]];
                filePath = datPath;
                [mailController addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath] mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.csv",[filesarray objectAtIndex:i]]];
            }
            [mailController setSubject:message];
            [mailController setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
            [self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
        }
```